# Separating sqlcmd's stdout and stderr

Tags: sqlcmd, azure-synapse

I need to implement a test harness for Azure SQL Data Warehouse using sqlcmd on Linux.  In my test, I want to capture any error messages encountered by sqlcmd, but send the query results to /dev/null (using -o argument). In reviewing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx, it seems that if -o is used, -r1 is meaningless.

```
 -r[0 | 1]
    Redirects the error message output to the screen (stderr). If you do not specify a parameter or if you specify 0, only error messages that have a  severity level of 11 or higher are redirected. If you specify 1, all error message output including PRINT is redirected. Has no effect if you use -o. By default, messages are sent to stdout.
```

Having trouble understanding why stdout and stderr would be intermingled in this way.

Is my only recourse to run sqlcmd in the background while writing "stdout+stderr" to a named pipe and then strip off the error messages from the named pipe's results?

I don't want to incur any delay in writing the output, but do want to return the full results to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does "sqlcmd  -i debug_dir/test2.sql -r1 2> /tmp/2.out 1> /tmp/1.out" work for you?

I tried it on my local box:

$> cat debug_dir/test2.sql

select * from test1;
go

select * from test1 where i = 'a';
go

select * from test2;
go

$> sqlcmd -S XXX -N -U YYY -P ZZZ -d AAA -I -i debug_dir/test2.sql -r1 2> /tmp/2.out 1> /tmp/1.out

$> cat /tmp/1.out 
i           j           k

---

```
      2           1           3
      1           2           3
      2           1           4
```

(3 rows affected)
a           b           c

---

```
      2           1           4
     11          12           4
     11          12           3
      2           1           3
```

$> cat /tmp/2.out 
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Server XXX, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.
Msg 104309, Level 16, State 1, Server XXX, Line 1
There are no batches in the input script.

You can redirect to /dev/null instead of /tmp/1.out

I hope that helps.